# I'm having trouble sending a post request in nodeExpress

Tags: node.js, express

i really don't know what it could be a problem but everytime i try to post i get a log error : ER_BAD_NULL_ERROR: Column 'idmedecin' cannot be null
i've seen allot of similar questions (trouble in post req) but nothing solved my problem and i cannot see what im doing wrong since idmedcin is clearly not NULL
reqLink used = http://***.***.***.107:3000/rendezvousinsert?idmedecin=1&idpatient=1&date=546654&etat=1

```
  const mysql = require('mysql');

const express = require('express');

var app = express();

const bodyparser = require('body-parser');



app.use(bodyparser.json());



var mysqlConnection = mysql.createConnection({

    host: 'localhost',

    user: 'root',

    password: '',

    database: 'pim',

    multipleStatements: true

});



mysqlConnection.connect((err) => {

    if (!err)

        console.log('DB connection succeded.');

    else

        console.log('DB connection failed \n Error : ' + JSON.stringify(err, undefined, 2));

});





app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Express server is runnig at port no : 3000'));

app.post('/rendezvousinsert/',(req,res)=> {
    var post= {
      idmedecin : req.body.idmedecin ,
      idpatient : req.body.idpatient ,
      date :  req.body.date ,
      etat : req.body.etat
    };
    mysqlConnection.query('INSERT INTO rendezvous SET ?' , post, function(error) {
        if (error) {
            console.log(error.message);
        } else {
            console.log('success');
        }
    });
});
```

here is my table structure [image: table]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to get the fields from the request body, but in your example you send them as query params.

I think the correct way is to send the object inside the POST body and not as query params, but if you want the request to remain as in your example, it should look like this:

```
var post= {
   idmedecin : req.query.idmedecin ,
   idpatient : req.query.idpatient ,
   date :  req.query.date ,
   etat : req.query.etat
 };
```

Answer (score 2):

You're sending data through `query string` `http://..***.107:3000/rendezvousinsert?idmedecin=1&idpatient=1&date=546654&etat=1` but trying to access it through `req.body`

`idmedecin=1&idpatient=1&date=546654&etat=1` This data is available as

```
req.query.idmedecin // 1
req.query.idpatient // 1
req.query.date // 546654
// etc
```